# Is "along the way" parenthetical in the following example?

Tags: punctuation

> They dated for two years. Then(,) along the way, their love started to fade.

I wonder if *along the way* here is parenthetical or not. Is it the same as this structure?

> Then, without even noticing it, their love started to fade.

Or maybe it's up to me whether I want it to be parenthetical? And therefore add a comma after *Then*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that "along the way" is parenthetical, or non-essential.

> Then their love started to fade.

would be a valid sentence, with the same basic meaning, although without an added nuance or detail.

The other example in the question:

> Then, without even noticing it, their love started to fade.

uses the same structure, although the meaning is not exactly the same. (It is also a case of elision, as it is short for):

> Then, without their even noticing it, their love started to fade.

In both sentences the parenthetical clause should be set off by commas, one before and one after the clause.

Answer (score 2):

**along the way** is an idiomatic phrase. See below, for others.

I see no reason to get tied up in the words parenthetical or  non-essential as this question is a matter of style, and, **not a grammar question.**

The phrase is often used.

But I would call it **an adverbial phrase since it answers the question:**
 **When** did their love start to fade**?

**Then, their love started to fade along the way.**

It could have faded **at the end**, **at the beginning** or at some other time.

Pre-positioning the phrase is merely style and does not change how it functions in the sentence as an adverbial phrase.

No, **along the way** is like but not exactly the same as: without their even noticing it.

Their love started to fade without **their** even noticing it.

That is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about punctuation depend on what style guide you adopt. There is no universal agreement on punctuating English.

My personal guide is whether there would be a pause if the sentence were spoken. I would say

> Then *brief pause* along the way *brief pause* their love started to fade

so I would write

> Then, along the way, their love started to fade.

The purpose of punctuation is to provide to a reader clues to meaning that are given to a listener by stress and interruptions. Punctuation does not exist in the grammar of English as a spoken language.

**EDIT**: English as spoken (except by Viktor Borge) has no punctuation, but has many other extra-verbal cues to meaning that do not exist in written English. There is a significant statistical correlation between quite brief interruptions to the speaker's habitual pace of speech and the use of commas specified as appropriate by many style guides. I did not intend to imply that questions such as the recommended distinctions among the usage of comma, semicolon, colon, dash, and period can also be determined by mimicking quite brief interruptions in a speaker's habitual pace of speech. That is a useful **guide** to the presence or absence of a comma, but it does not guarantee adherence to all the requirements of any specific edition of any specific style guide.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with the idea that punctuation is at all closely related to where a speaker would pause. Punctuation is part of **written** English, and has only rough correspondence with pauses in spoken English. One exception: When a writer of dialog wants to indicate broken speech, such as an injured or out of breath person might say, pauses may be shown with dashes or ellipsis marks. But that is a very special case. For example, the difference between a comma and a semi-colon is significant in written English, but is not normally detectable by sound in spoken English.

Comment: @David Siegel I shall edit my comment because you have interpreted it to mean that all punctuation corresponds to pauses of different length. My point was that usage of commas, the topic of this question, is determined by style guides, which are not uniform, but is correlated with brief pauses in normal spoken English

Comment: parenthetical and non-essential are not the same thing.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow I agree that commas correlate better with spoken pauses than many other forms of punctuation (although I do hear quote marks pronounced as 'quote' and 'endquote'). There are certainly some differences of opnion about the use of punctuation, as there is about word usage. I understand you were not claiming that all punctuation merely records speech pauses. I still think that basing decisions on whether to use a comma on the placement of pauses in spoken English is getting things backwards, or sideways. Punctuation is its own thing, part of written English. ...

Comment: @Lambie I quite agree with you, but I cannot find where I conflated the two or even used them.

Comment: ... comma use neither determines, nor is determined by, speech pauses. They are related, parallel things, but follow separate rules and practices.

Comment: @Lambie, I think that should have been a comment on my answer. Many non-essential clauses are not parenthetical, but most if not all parenthetical ones are non-essential. "along the way" in the question here is both, in my view.

Comment: @David Siegel I could try to explain to you the difference between "determine," a verb I did not use, and "is a significant statistical correlation between," a phrase I did use. Because, however, you appear eager to misinterpret, I shall not bother.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Ok, next time.  Anyway, along the way is used a lot in speech...So, I just don't buy that it is either parenthetical or non-essential. It could be stylistically purposeful....

Comment: @Jeff Morrow  I am well aware of the difference between "determines" and "is correlated with". I have significant background in stats. I agree that I was disputing a stranger statement than you made, although one i think your answer implied. I agree that comma use is related to speech pauses, but think it unwise to use speech pauses to decide whehter to include a comma at a given point.

Comment: @Lambie, many parentheticals are frequently used. Many are  stylistically purposeful. That does not make them less parenthetical. In this case, if "along the way" is left out, there is still a valid sentence whose core meaning is unchanged. Does that not make it non-essential?

Comment: Their love started to fade at the end. Their love started to fade at the very beginning. Their love started to fade along the way. This is about style, not anything else. All those could be pre-positioned. They are not parenthetical. They are part of the meaning and address when the love started to fade.

Comment: @David Siegel In case you did not notice, I specifically rejected the implication of "guarantee." Had I intended to imply "determine" in the senses of either "cause" or "has a coefficient of correlation of 100%,"  I would have used those or equivalent terms. You have given no indication of your qualifications in inferential statistics other than your own self-assessment. Based on your conflation of correlation and determination, I am not convinced that your self-assessment is reliable.

Comment: @Jeff  It is indeed true that correlation is not the same as determination. A classic phrase to remind one of this is "correlation is not causation". When you wrote, in the initial answer "My personal guide is whether there would be a pause" I understood that to mean that if there was a pause, you would use a comma, thus you were using the pause to decide on or determine comma placement. That was the passage I have been responding to.

Comment: @Jeff As to qualifications, perhaps i shouldn't have brought them up, as an error by a well-qualified person is still an error. However, my first published technical paper (many years ago) involved doing an analysis of variance to interpret the responses of subjects in a study of color vision. I am not a professional statistician. I am a software engineer, My father was an experimental psychologist, and i followed his work closely, and for a time provided computer support for it. I could say more, but I am getting rather off-topic.

Comment: @ David Siegel Fair enough. And I did see that your initial point indicated the need for an qualifying and expanding my initial response.